# Socket.io client connects but doesn't emit in a Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, socket.io

I'm trying to get socket.io to work in Unity.

On both the client (Unity) and the server (Node) I can see that it was able to connect successfully.

However, the server never receives the "message" event that I'm emitting upon connection.

I don't see any errors.

Both the client and the server are using socket.io v4.

I'm using Unity version 2021.3.23f1.

I'll note that when connecting to the same server from a JavaScript client everything works perfectly, so the problem seems to be in Unity.

I need this for a Unity library I'm writing, so I can't have a paid Unity asset as a dependency.
For example:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/socket-io-v3-v4-client-basic-standalone-webgl-196557

I tried the following NuGet (installed via NuGetForUnity):
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SocketIOClient/

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using SocketIOClient;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start() {
        Connect();
    }

    async Task Connect()
    {
        var client = new SocketIO("ws://localhost:8090");

        client.OnConnected += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("OnConnected: " + e);

            await client.EmitAsync("message", "bla");
        };

        client.OnError += (sender, e) => {
            Debug.Log("OnError: " + e);
        };

        await client.ConnectAsync();
    }
}
```

I also tried using a unity package which is supposed to wrap the above library in a way that'll make it work with unity. I'm getting the exact same result.

https://github.com/itisnajim/SocketIOUnity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start() {
        var uri = new Uri("ws://localhost:8090");
        
        var client = new SocketIOUnity(uri);

        client.OnConnected += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("OnConnected");

            await client.EmitAsync("message", "bla"); // client.Emit doesn't work either
        };

        client.OnError += (sender, e) => {
            Debug.Log("OnError: " + e);
        };

        client.Connect();
    }
}
```

Here's the Node server:

```
const httpServer = require("http").createServer();

const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, { cors: true });

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("connection");
});

io.on("message", (value) => {
    console.log("message", value);
});

httpServer.listen(8090);
```

Comment: Did you write the server yourself? I understand that the error is in the client, but it may be helpful to see the server code either way.

Comment: The best way to handle these situations is to start again from scratch, and slowly add everything back until you have the error.

Comment: I wrote the server myself, though I'm pretty certain the issue is not there. There's no error, that's what makes it hard to debug :)

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b I added a very simple server in Node. It's now even more obvious that the probem is in the client.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late response. Thank you for uploading the server code. Have you tried my suggestion of stripping everything down until you get the error? And maybe you shouldn’t use events in this case. Maybe have it emit after the await for connected instead of the o connected event?

Comment: Hi, no worries. What you see above is the stripped down version, I don't think it can get any more minimal than that.

I tried emitting after await client.ConnectAsync() and got the same result.

Comment: Have you tried emitting any other events? What about events that don’t require an additional argument? Sorry, I’m grasping at straws here. From documentation it seems that you might also be able to emit a SocketMessage class instead of whatever overload you are using.